# How to find the minimal dimension of a primitive matrix for a given Perron number?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a Perron number of degree $n$(the degree of its minimal polynomial).

If $p$ is a Perron number, then there is a primitive integral matrix $A$ with spectral radius $p$. (Lind, 1983)

Even if the companion matrix $B$ of the minimal polynomial of $p$ has a negative trace. In this case the dimension of $A$ must strictly exceed $n$.

In a paper of Lind, he gave an example:

$B=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 46 \\
 1 & 0 & 15 \\
    0 & 1 & -3
\end{bmatrix}$

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &12 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 9 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$A$ is a $10$-dimensional primitive integral matrix with the same spectral radius of $B$.
I used the algorithm of Lind to construct other matrices, e.g.

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \\
2343010 & 11 & 8 & 12 & 0 & 81 & 0 & 17 & 0 & 65 & 0 & 10 & 0 & \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Is there a lower dimensional primitive integral matrix with spectral radius of $B$?

Or in general:
Is there a way to find the minimal dimensional primitive integral matrix for a given Perron number?